# Removing Char 10, Char 13 characters from aliased columns in conjunction with using case clause SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I would like the query below (second box) to remove the char 10 and char 13 characters.  I tried to use the syntax for two aliased fields seen below.  I receive an issue where intellisense tries to chop it up into different queries.  I can use the syntax for one aliased column, but not two.  How can I do this better?

```
Comments = REPLACE(REPLACE([Comments], CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') AS 'SAP REMARKS'

NOTES   = REPLACE(REPLACE([Notes], CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') AS 'WMS NOTES'
```

I have the following query and it executes fine.  I will change the date from a hardcoded value once I get the data to pull.

```
SELECT  
    [DocEntry],
    CASE 
       WHEN DOCSTATUS = 'O' THEN 'OPEN'
       WHEN DOCSTATUS = 'C' THEN 'CLOSED/CANCELLED'
      ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'SAP STATUS',
    [STATUS] AS 'WMS STATUS',
    confirmed,
    [CardCode], [CardName],
    Comments AS 'SAP REMARKS',
    NOTES AS 'WMS NOTES',
    [DocDate], [DocDueDate] 
FROM
    [DBASE1].[ENV].[dbo].[ORDR]B
LEFT JOIN 
    [DBASE2].[ENV].[dbo].[OUTBOUNDORHEADER] A ON orderid = DocEntry
WHERE 
    DOCDATE = '2018-09-06'    


SELECT  
    [DocEntry],
    CASE
       WHEN DOCSTATUS = 'O' THEN 'OPEN'
       WHEN DOCSTATUS = 'C' THEN 'CLOSED/CANCELLED'
       ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'SAP STATUS',
    [STATUS] AS 'WMS STATUS',
    confirmed,
    [CardCode], [CardName],
    Comments = REPLACE(REPLACE([Comments], CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') AS 'SAP REMARKS',
    NOTES = REPLACE(REPLACE([Notes], CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') AS 'WMS NOTES',
    [DocDate]
FROM 
    [DBASE1].[ENV].[dbo].[ORDR]B
LEFT JOIN 
    [DBASE2].[ENV].[dbo].[OUTBOUNDORHEADER] A ON orderid = DocEntry
WHERE 
    DOCDATE = '2018-09-06'
```

Comment: Can you post the whole query you're trying to run?  Are you trying to chop off the characters from your results, or actually update the table to remove the characters from those fields?

Comment: Yes for sure here is the query

Comment: Can you post the version that Intellisense doesn't like? I have a suspicion I know what's going on, but at this point I'm only guessing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by " intellisense tries to chop it up into different queries."   I've never seen anything that fits this description.

Comment: If you're not trying to update the source table, just take the `comments = ` and `notes =` parts out

Comment: I do not wish to update the source only the results.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it in order to get your question answered. Up voted for tenacity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the extra query. Just what I thought. You're aliasing your column twice, once with the `xxx = ...`, then again with the `AS`. Here you go:

```
SELECT
  [DocEntry]
 ,CASE
    WHEN DOCSTATUS = 'O' THEN 'OPEN'
    WHEN DOCSTATUS = 'C' THEN 'CLOSED/CANCELLED'
    ELSE NULL
  END AS [SAP STATUS]
 ,[STATUS] AS [WMS STATUS]
 ,confirmed
 ,[CardCode]
 ,[CardName]
 ,REPLACE(REPLACE([Comments], CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') AS [SAP REMARKS]
 ,REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST([Notes] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') AS [WMS NOTES]
 ,[DocDate]
 ,[DocDueDate]
FROM
  [DBASE1].[ENV].[dbo].[ORDR] AS B
  LEFT JOIN
    [DBASE2].[ENV].[dbo].[OUTBOUNDORHEADER] AS A
      ON
      orderid = DocEntry
WHERE
  DOCDATE = '2018-09-06';
```

**Edit**: Added the explicit CAST to the `Notes` column, per comments.

Comment: I receive the following error message when running the query     Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: For the text typed column or columns, wrap a CAST AS VARCHAR(MAX) around the name in the function call. Should fix it.

Comment: Comments is Nvarchar and notes is text.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following should work fine:

```
SELECT  [DocEntry]
,CASE DOCSTATUS WHEN 'O' THEN 'OPEN' WHEN 'C' THEN 'CLOSED/CANCELLED' ELSE NULL END AS 'SAP STATUS'
,[STATUS] AS 'WMS STATUS' 
,confirmed
,[CardCode]
,[CardName]
,replace(replace([Comments],Char(13),''),CHAR(10),'') AS 'SAP REMARKS'
,replace(replace([Notes],Char(13),''),CHAR(10),'') AS 'WMS NOTES'
,[DocDate]
,[DocDueDate] 
FROM [DBASE1].[ENV].[dbo].[ORDR]B
left join [DBASE2].[ENV].[dbo].[OUTBOUNDORHEADER]A
on orderid = DocEntry
where DOCDATE = '2018-09-06'
```

Comment: Error message below populates when running query Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: What data type 'Comments' column has?

Comment: try: cast(replace(replace(cast([Comments] as nvarchar(max)),Char(13),''),CHAR(10),'') as ntext)

Comment: Comments is Nvarchar and notes is text.

Comment: Use the similar approach with 'Notes' column, no need for column 'Comments'.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following (without the `comments =` portion of your original syntax):

```
SELECT  [DocEntry]
,CASE
WHEN DOCSTATUS = 'O' 
THEN 'OPEN'
WHEN DOCSTATUS = 'C'
THEN 'CLOSED/CANCELLED'
ELSE NULL END AS 'SAP STATUS'
,[STATUS] AS 'WMS STATUS' 
,confirmed
,[CardCode]
,[CardName]
,replace(replace([Comments],Char(13),''),CHAR(10),'') AS 'SAP REMARKS'
,replace(replace([Notes],Char(13),''),CHAR(10),'') AS 'WMS NOTES'
,[DocDate]
 FROM [DBASE1].[ENV].[dbo].[ORDR]B
 left join [DBASE2].[ENV].[dbo].[OUTBOUNDORHEADER]A
on orderid = DocEntry
where DOCDATE = '2018-09-06'
```

Typically you would only need to use something like `comments =` if you are trying to update the source table, set the value of a declared variable, or similar.

Comment: Thank you, for your response, I do not want to update the table.  I only want the results to populate without the table being updated.

Comment: @APH, actually the `comments = ` syntax is a valid way to alias a column. [Aaron Bertrand prefers it](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases), but I'm still on the fence.

Comment: @EricBrandt I agree that it's valid; I updated my response to specify "need to use"